# Displaying Error Message With Its Line Number

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-word

I want to catch errors of a word document with line numbers of word document(Not vb.net Program line number) from where error occurred , i am able to get the error but unable to catch the line number containing error

I have tried this,

```
  If objDoc.Range.Font.Size = 10 And objDoc.Range.Font.Name = "Arial" Then
        If objDoc.Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorBlack Then
        End If
        MsgBox("ok")
    Else
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(TextBox1.Text & "\" & "Error.txt", True)
        objWriter.Write("Error:check font styles" & vbCrLf)
        objWriter.Close()
    End If
```

Here i am able to catch the error in txt file but no idea how to find the line number containing the error.

Plz anyone help me with the required logic,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Generating line numbers in exception stack traces is a built-in feature for the CLR. You do however have to provide the information it needs to map a code address to a line number.

1) Switch to the Release configuration of your project. 
2) Project --> Properties --> Compile tab --> Advanced Compile Options. 
3) Change the "Generate debug info" setting from pdb-only to Full. Deploy the .pdb files along with your program.

You will get Error line number from "StackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber()" in program

Try following code:

```
  Private Sub IntegerValues()
    Dim abc As Integer = 0
    Dim xyz As Integer = 1 / abc
  End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
    Try
        IntegerValues()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim st As New StackTrace(True)
        st = New StackTrace(ex, True)
        MessageBox.Show("Line: " & st.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber().ToString, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: i have tried the following code but it is displaying the wrong line number in the error log..

Comment: Make sure that your code is running under "Release Configuration Mode" and not in "Debug configuration Mode"... and after that Project --> Properties --> Compile tab --> Advanced Compile Options Change the "Generate debug info" setting from pdb-only to Full. also make sure that .pdb files included with program file. then this code will run fine.

Comment: I don't how to include .pdb files can u help me with this also please..sorry for the trouble but m a little bit new at this.

Comment: From where you are running your program? from bin --> release folder?

Comment: you will find .pdb files in release folder if not then go to project properties, compile tab , advance compile option Change the "Generate debug info" setting from pdb-only to Full. is it also done?

Comment: yes i have changed the settings..and i have found the .pdb file then what to do next??

Comment: ok.. so .pdb files is generated in release folder? if not rebuild solution again.

Comment: i have found the .pdb file then what to do next??

Comment: make sure that your .exe file and .pdb files is exists in same folder now, run the code.. if it is also not working show me your code via team viewer if you dont mind..

Comment: ya its in the same folder but it is showing me the wrong Line number when i execute the file and i have used stack Trace in if else statement..will it execute in if else statement

Comment: no you can not execute it in else statement in that case it will show the line number of "Dim st As New StackTrace(True)" if error will caught in "Try Catch" then only it will show the line number from where error is thrown... in your case you need to write line number manually.

Comment: see i have to check the font name,size and color in a word file and if an error is caught it will show the error with the line number in an error log i have used if..else is this possible using try catch??

Comment: Which line number you want to display exactly? Line number in else case? or line number of if case?

Comment: you can use this code for get line number from else case same if you want in if case write Throw New System.Exception("An exception has occurred.")  Dim dd As Boolean = False
        Try
            If dd Then
                MsgBox("ok")
            Else
                Throw New System.Exception("An exception has occurred.")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim st As New StackTrace(True)
            st = New StackTrace(ex, True)
            MessageBox.Show("Line: " & st.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber().ToString, "Error")
        End Try
       
    End Sub

Comment: write your code in try catch and use "Throw New System.Exception("An exception has occurred.") whenever you want to write log it will go to   catch and write line number from where exception thrown manually.. if you are writing below the code from where you want line number do Dim int As Integer = st.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber() - 1 and display int.tostring() in your log file.

Comment: in your case this solution will not work.. above solution will give line number of vb.net file where logical code written.